# How to map the nested Json in TypeScript in Angular 2

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular2-services, handsontable

I am not able to map the nested json in TypeScript in Angular2. .

My Json structure is like this:

```
{
  "templateId": 5,
  "sectionsList": [
    {
      "sectionName": "ITEMHEADER",
      "subSectionsList": [
        {

        }
      ],
      "fieldProperties": [
        {
          "fieldName": "CustomerItemReferenceNo",
          "isUsedForTotals": "N"
        },
        {
          "fieldName": "LFItemReferenceNo",
          "isUsedForTotals": "N"
        },
        {
          "fieldName": "ItemName",
          "isUsedForTotals": "N"
        },
        {
          "fieldName": "ItemDescription",
          "isUsedForTotals": "N"
        },
        {
          "fieldName": "LFDivision",
          "value": "CMN_V_ORGANIZATION.DIVISION_CODE",
          "isUsedForTotals": "N"
        },
        {
          "fieldName": "LFDepartment",
          "value": "CMN_V_ORGANIZATION.DEPARTMENT_CODE",
          "isUsedForTotals": "N"
        },
        {
          "fieldName": "LFSourcingOffice",
          "value": "CMN_V_OFFICE.OFFICE_CODE",
          "isUsedForTotals": "N"
        }
      ],
      "total": 0
    },
    {
      "sectionName": "MATERIAL",
      "subSectionsList": [
        {
          "subSectionName": "FABRIC",
          "fieldProperties": [
            {
              "fieldName": "MaterialPriority",
              "isUsedForTotals": "N"
            },
            {
              "fieldName": "SupplierMaterialID",
              "isUsedForTotals": "N"
            },
            {
              "fieldName": "CountryofOrigin",
              "value": "CMN_V_COUNTRY.COUNTRY_CODE",
              "isUsedForTotals": "N"
            },
            {
              "fieldName": "MATERIALPRICE",
              "isUsedForTotals": "Y"
            },
            {
              "fieldName": "TotalFabricCost",
              "isUsedForTotals": "Y"
            }
          ],
          "totals": 0
        }
      ],
      "fieldProperties": [

      ],
      "total": 0
    },
    {
      "sectionName": "MATERIAL",
      "subSectionsList": [
        {
          "subSectionName": "TRIMS",
          "fieldProperties": [
            {
              "fieldName": "MaterialPriority",
              "isUsedForTotals": "N"
            },
            {
              "fieldName": "SupplierMaterialID",
              "isUsedForTotals": "N"
            },
            {
              "fieldName": "MaterialContent&Description",
              "isUsedForTotals": "N"
            },
            {
              "fieldName": "CountryofOrigin",
              "value": "CMN_V_COUNTRY.COUNTRY_CODE",
              "isUsedForTotals": "N"
            },
            {
              "fieldName": "MATERIALPRICE",
              "isUsedForTotals": "Y"
            },
            {
              "fieldName": "TotalTrimCost",
              "isUsedForTotals": "Y"
            }
          ],
          "totals": 0
        }
      ],
      "fieldProperties": [

      ],
      "total": 0
    },
    {
      "sectionName": "PACKAGING",
      "subSectionsList": [
        {

        }
      ],
      "fieldProperties": [
        {
          "fieldName": "Packagingcostperpackingcomponent",
          "isUsedForTotals": "Y"
        },
        {
          "fieldName": "TotalPackagingCost",
          "isUsedForTotals": "Y"
        }
      ],
      "total": 0
    }
  ]
}
```

And the class is have written is to map the Json is like this:

```
export interface Template1 { 
    templateId: number;
    sectionsList:SectionsList[];    
}

 export interface SectionsList { 
    sectionName: string;
    subSectionsList:SubSectionsList[];
    fieldProperties:FieldProperties[];
    total:number;  
 }

 export interface SubSectionsList { 
    subSectionName: string;    
    fieldProperties:FieldProperties[];
    total:number;  
 }

 export interface FieldProperties { 
    fieldName: string;   
    value:string; 
    isUsedForTotals:string;
 }
```

And my service to map from Json is:

```
getTemplate1():Observable<Template1 []>{
        return this.http.get("http://localhost:8080/RestEasyWebApp/rest/restAPI/getCostSheet/1")
           .map((response: Response) => response.json())          
            .do(data => console.log([data]))
            .catch(this.handleError);
    }
```

Note: eg-> Only from '*templateId*' i am getting data but not from 'sectionList.sectionName'

Comment: Maybe for the caps? SectionList -> sectionList

Comment: What exactly is the problem? Where cannot you get data?

Comment: I am calling this function like this.itemService.getTemplate1().subscribe(
                     temp1 => this.sect1=temp1,    
                     error =>  this.errorMessage = <any>error);
But i am only getting value in Template1 only, not in the variables of SectionsList ,SubSectionsList and FieldProperties

Comment: Okay, have you checked that you are actually received all response in network tab? Where do you establish that the values are not coming? Have you console logged it in the subscribe, or is the values not there in the `.do` as well? Or where? :)

Comment: Yes I am getting all response in network Tab

Answer (score 0):

SectionList is array of object. So you have to fetch sectionName of first object  like:

Suggestion : better use subscribe.

```
getTemplate1():Observable<Template1 []>{
    return this.http.get("http://localhost:8080/RestEasyWebApp/rest/restAPI/getCostSheet/1")
       .map((response: Response) => response.json())          
       .do((data) => 
           {
            console.log(data);
            console.log(data.sectionList[0].sectionName) 
            })
        .catch(this.handleError);
}
```

Comment: Yes i am calling this function like this.itemService.getTemplate1().subscribe(
                     temp1 => this.sect1=temp1,    
                     error =>  this.errorMessage = <any>error);
But i am only getting value in Template1 only, not in SectionsList ,SubSectionsList and FieldProperties